# Receive coins from my physical wallet

Tags: wallet

I'm new at this. I opened a wallet on my computer, I  have a physical wallet I'm trying to get the coins from my physical wallet to my computer. I went into my wallet, clicked help, selected the debug window option, clicked on the console tap typed in my importprivkey  then what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

By physical wallet I assume you mean like a printed paper wallet. But your paper wallet should be an address and the corresponding private key (don't share this!). To access it all you need to do is import it to bitcoin-qt through one of the options. To do it through console:

```
importprivkey <private key>
```

Where  is your private key. It should take your client like 30-60 mins to rescan the block chain to update the balance.